# Understanding Python import priority

Tags: python, python-module

I need some clarification on how module and class level imports are handled when coexisting in the same namespace. See the following examples:

**Works:**

```
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

**Fails:**

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

> Error: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no
>   attribute 'datetime'

**Works:**

```
from datetime import datetime # Is this ignored?
import datetime
print datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

What exactly is happening in the 3rd example? Is the second module import replacing the class-specific first import? Does this mean that module and class level imports shouldn't be mixed in the same namespace?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no priority is such. The outcome is determined by the order in which `import` statements are executed, as follows.

If you try to import several things called `X` into your namespace, each import would rebind `X` to whatever it's importing.

Therefore at the end it will be last import that'll be in effect as far as the name `X` in concerned.

This is precisely what happens in your third example:

```
from datetime import datetime # This isn't ignored, but the name is immediately rebound
                              # by the next line
import datetime               # Rebinds the name
```

Answer (score 2):

Some of the IDE's that support python would give you the explanation, but yes, you're redefining (overwriting, replacing) the import in the 3rd example.  Each name within a file is distinct.  If you need access to a module and a class that share a name you need to use something like `from datetime import datetime as dt`.

Answer (score 1):

An import is really just an assignment: it sets a name in your current namespace. So, in the third case, you set the name `datetime` as equal to the datetime class, then immediately reassign it to the datetime module.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example imports the `datetime` module and provides a `datetime` label in the local namespace representing it, then calls the `utcnow()` method of the `datetime` object belonging to the `datetime` module.  The second adds the `datetime.datetime` object (not the module) to the local namespace with the label `datetime`, but the `datetime` object has no attribute `datetime`, so you get the exception.  The third example assigns the `datetime.datetime` object to the label of that name in the namespace, then reassigns the label to the `datetime` module.  So ignoring the mechanics of `import` that are irrelevant to this question (basically, adding modules to `sys.modules` if they are not there yet), what you have is equivalent to:

```
datetime = sys.modules['datetime']
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

then

```
datetime = sys.modules['datetime'].datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

then

```
datetime = sys.modules['datetime'].datetime
datetime = sys.modules['datetime']
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to do it like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

this code, on the other hand, would do exactly what you want it to:

```
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.utcnow()
```